# Jenkins Add Post Build Activity for all builds in Jenkins server

Tags: post, android-activity, build, jenkins

I would like to know, how to copy the "Post Build Activity" setting to all other builds in the same Jenkins server.

Example :

1. I have 100 or more builds are running in the Jenkins server.
2. Recently I have installed "Work Space Cleanup" plugin in the Jenkins Server
3. Now I have to enable/set the "Work Space Cleanup" property which is there in "Post Build Activity" for all 100 builds.

I am looking out for a common place in Jenkins to update the setting which intern updates the same setting for all 100 builds.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Bhupal.

Comment: Is your query resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you require [Configuration Slicing plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) has removed the support for the exact plugin you're asking for, but it would probably be possible to make a batch file, python script or something that removes the files wanted and then slice it among the projects.

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying *builds*, i assume you mean to say *projects*/*jobs*. When you create a job, the configuration is stored in config.xml which is present on Jenkins server under the following path:

```
/path_to_jenkins_setup/jobs/job_name/config.xml
```

Just open the file and find the relevant portion that you need to replicate in other jobs. Create a script to copy the relevant portion to all jobs' config.xml.

- *Don't forget to restart Jenkins after making the changes*. Alternatively, you can reload your changes by clicking on `Reload Configuration from Disk` which is present in `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins` section.